# datetime.now() in Windows vs WSL vs Linux?

Tags: python, linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I see a difference in the datetime.now() function in Windows Python 3.11 vs WSL Python 3.10 and Linux Python 3.10. On Windows, I get duplicate entries. On WSL and Linux, I don't.

I am converting a test system from primarily being used with Python in WSL to using Python in Windows natively and hit a kind of weird issue. At one place the previous author was recording the datetime.now() at the outset of the script, then checking its delta later to see if it was still the same (I'm legit not sure why, but this is what was going on). This suddenly broke with Python in Windows. After some digging, it seems that it's because there is literally no delta in the two datetime.now() calls most of the time. I tried it with WSL and it still worked. Here's an example of what I'm talking about in germ:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
for i in range(0,10):
    print(f"date and time is: {dt.now()}")
```

With Windows, this is what it prints out:

```
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:09:39.393765
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:09:39.393765
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:09:39.408956
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:09:39.408956
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:09:39.408956
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:09:39.409962
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:09:39.409962
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:09:39.409962
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:09:39.409962
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:09:39.410971
```

As you can see, multiple entries are identical.

Same system and code with WSL:

```
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:10:58.658753
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:10:58.658802
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:10:58.658828
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:10:58.658837
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:10:58.658857
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:10:58.658880
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:10:58.658888
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:10:58.658892
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:10:58.658911
date and time is: 2024-02-26 17:10:58.658935
```

No duplicates.

My original assumption was that this was because of the overhead of WSL being a VM, but I'm not really sure. I just found it odd and couldn't really find any help with it online as it seems like usually the reason people run into datetime.now() "not updating" is because they're assigning the output to a variable and not rerunning it, but I am running it again each time.

I was curious, so I just ran it again on a Linux box I have set up (Ubuntu 22.04), and it never saw any duplicates either.

```
date and time is: 2024-02-27 09:38:16.767813
date and time is: 2024-02-27 09:38:16.767853
date and time is: 2024-02-27 09:38:16.767860
date and time is: 2024-02-27 09:38:16.767864
date and time is: 2024-02-27 09:38:16.767869
date and time is: 2024-02-27 09:38:16.767873
date and time is: 2024-02-27 09:38:16.767878
date and time is: 2024-02-27 09:38:16.767882
date and time is: 2024-02-27 09:38:16.767889
date and time is: 2024-02-27 09:38:16.767894
```

I checked the Python versions in each and do see a difference:
Windows: Python 3.11.8
WSL: Python 3.10.12
Ubuntu: Python 3.10.12

The CPU's are different, too, if that matters in this case:

Windows:
i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz, 3192 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)

Linux:
lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Address sizes:         39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz
CPU family:          6
Model:               94
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
Stepping:            3
CPU max MHz:         3400.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000

It's easy to get the code I was working with to work with Windows' Python by adding a time.sleep(0.000001), and I'm not sure if the offending code is even needed, but I'm just curious why this is happening and wondered if anyone could shed any light on it.

Thanks!

Comment: Timers on different operating systems and hardware platforms have different resolutions. The `time` module offers some options for higher precision where available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Python uses underlying operating system features, some of its behaviors will differ depending on what OS fuels your runtime environment. And while  your test is bit flawed because you use different Python versions, unifying these would most likely yield to similar results.

Windows has historically had issues with time granularity, where the clock update frequency is not as high as on some Linux configurations. The precision of time measurements and the resolution of system time updates can significantly vary, leading to differences in how frequently `datetime.now()` returns a new value. The addition of `time.sleep(0.000001)` in your script likely forces the Python interpreter to yield execution long enough for the system clock to update, thus avoiding duplicates. This workaround is generally acceptable but should be used judiciously, understanding that it introduces a small overhead to each loop iteration which might be not really needed if such detailed time granularity is not really necessary.

Comment: Thanks. That largely makes sense to me and comports with assumptions I was making. Have to take your word for it regarding Windows time granularity. I guess a subtext quesiton I was asking was if Python on Windows had a bug, but I'm guessing not given what you said. It'd be interesting to get a 1:1 comparison on the same box with all things (as much as possible) being equal, but well, I'm not sure it's worth the effort.

Comment: Unless this is critical for your application it most likely is not. It's worth knowing some things are different due to OS differences, but all I'd probably do is to re-run my tests with the same Python version (highest version you can use, best 3.12 as of now) and if the result show up the same, I'd try to live with it :) Also if my answer addresses your question, please mark it as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Thanks again and done. Didn't realize I had that power as a "new" user (been visiting for years without ever asking a question).